# Stripe checkout. Checking client amount

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

Is it possible to check whether or not the amount that the client sees and the amount that the server sees is the same?

Here I set the amount on the client side:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_1002UFB11gJ1sXBHcdDM8HPi',
    image: '/square-image.png',
    token: function(token) {
      // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: '2 widgets ($20.00)',
      amount: 2000
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
```

I am sending the token from client-side stripe callback to server:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php');

$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
  'customer' => $customer->id,

  'amount'   => 1000000000000,
  'currency' => 'usd'
  'email' => 'customer@example.com',
  'card'  => $token
));

echo '<h1>Successfully charged $2!</h1>';
?>
```

The client side number is clearly lower than the amount on the server side, and stripe charges the server side number.

Answer (score 3):

The way that we do this is by having the server check it.

The flow we have is:

1. The client makes an API call to the backend to fetch the price it should charge for a product.
2. The client calls the stripe api to get the token and displays the amount from step 1 to the client
3. Once the client has a token, call the backend API to make a charge passing both the token and amount (we call this a reconciliation amount).
4. On the backend, before calling the stripe create charge api, we first reconcile the amount by comparing the amount given from the client in step 3 to the amount the product should be (from step 1). If these don't match we do not proceed and return an error to the client.

Comment: Is this only the case with products? As in "products" that are created within Stripes interface? As I am using a customised checkout process and work out the price in my own system to display to the client - it varies depending on shipping location, however when I pass the amount to Stripe when creating a charge it seems to successfully allow charges of a smaller amount than the client was given during checkout.

Comment: I thought Stripe may have stored this information via the token and then if the same token was used when creating a charge with a different amount then it would throw an error, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @Brett no, in my case I am not using any stripe API other than create charge. I do not create any customer or products in stripe. I think the token is more or an identifier for a "charge source" which can be used to levy a charge. I don't think there is any notion of the token being associated to a given transaction/amount.

Comment: Oh ok. So you're basically just creating the "price" at both places and comparing them?

Comment: @Brett essentially yes, depending on the semantics of "creating". I have backend code capable of returning the price of the customer's "basket". I send this price to the frontend which is used for display purposes and passed back to the backend (along with the stripe token) to be reconciled against the "basket" before creating a "charge" in stripe.